# Involutive subbundles

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $TM\otimes\mathbb C$ be its complexified tangent bundle. Let $H$ be a complex subbundle of $TM\otimes\mathbb C$.

It can be happened that $H$  and $\bar H$ are involutive (i.e $[H,H]\subset H$ and $[\bar H,\bar H]\subset \bar H$) but $H\oplus \bar H$ is not involutive.

Can you please provide me in examples of this situation?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you started with $TM\otimes\Bbb C$ rather than an arbitrary complex vector bundle on $M$?

Comment: Yes, because I am looking for a non Levi flat CR manifold. Actually I am constructing one ..

Comment: Aha. OK. I still don't have an answer yet. So you're doing the special case where $H$ is the maximal complex subbundle of the real tangent bundle, which is far more specific than the question you posed.

Comment: But the example maybe is easy! Do you think $\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2; z+\bar z=w\bar w\}$ would work for my question?